# createImageHitRegion is not scaled with the image object

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am using a Kinetic.image object like this:

```
this.icon = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: self.x,
    y: self.y,
    offset: [32,32],
    image: self.imageItem.image,
    width: self.size,
    height: self.size,
    scale: self.scale,
    rotationDeg: self.angle,
    draggable: true
});
```

The image is a PNG with transparent pixels. I also create a image hit region:

```
self.icon.createImageHitRegion(function() {
    self.icon.getLayer().drawHit();
});
```

However, the hit region is wrong when I use the mouseover event. I suspect the hitregion is not scaled. Note that I also use offset so that the image rotates around it's center.

Am I doing something wrong of am I dealing with a bug here?

Comment: Your hit region may have to be recalculated with the animation. Maybe you could make a jsfiddle for people to mess with for faster answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when the image is created passing width and height. 
The library uses the width and height of the image to create the canvas to draw the hit region but the width and height is not used to scale the image that is drawn on the canvas.

If you search the kineticjs source you will see that inside createImageHitRegion there is a line that looks something like:

_context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

Add the width and height for the image and it should work as expected:

_context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

In my case I didn't have to pass the scale attribute while creating the image, please verify if this is working when you provide the scale attribute otherwise you will have to tweak createImageHitRegion to account for that.